# How do I set the theme for child controls with Infragistics?

Tags: wpf, themes, infragistics

I'm using the Infragistics WPF controls in a new project, and I'd like to take advantage of their themes support. I'm able to change the theme of my window (and toolbars) via the OnThemeChanged event, but I can't figure out how to change the theme of child controls (such as the XamDockManager), as they're added at runtime.

I'm new to WPF and Infragistics controls so any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer.

You need to set the control's `Theme` property to `Theme.CurrentTheme`. This will cause the controls to automatically pick up the new theme via their internal `OnThemeChanged` events.

This is the code I used, simplified a bit for this answer:

`<igDock:ContentPane xmlns:igTheme="clr-namespace:Infragistics.Windows.Themes;assembly=Infragistics3.Wpf.v9.1">`

`// other stuff`
...

`<igDock:XamDockManager "Theme="igTheme:ThemeManager.CurrentTheme" />`
`</igDock:ContentPane>`

Comment: I haven't tried it as I'm starting to look into this myself, but I believe you can use "[current]" instead of "igTheme:ThemeManager.CurrentTheme".